# PIL Image.paste not pasting small images over a big image

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create a full image and wish to paste smaller images onto it. This is an example of my code.

```
from PIL import Image
imageWidth=5760
imageHeight=2880
image_sheet = Image.new("RGB", (imageWidth, imageHeight), (255, 255, 255))
```

This creates an image object having the specifications as mentioned in the arguments.
Now I wish to paste an image of size 512*512 on this image.For example,

```
image=np.zeros((512,512))
image_sheet.paste(image,box=(0,0))    # I am trying to paste image of size 512*512 at upper left location of (0,0) as per the documentation
```

I get this error :

```
File "C:\Users\SSHUB\Anaconda3\envs\dl_torch\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1537, in paste
raise ValueError("cannot determine region size; use 4-item box")
ValueError: cannot determine region size; use 4-item box
```

If I use a 4 item box like this `image_sheet.paste(image,box=(0,0,512,512))` , I get the following error :

```
File "C:\Users\SSHUB\Anaconda3\envs\dl_torch\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1559, in paste
self.im.paste(im, box)
TypeError: color must be int or tuple
```

I am using pillow 9.0.1. Please guide as to how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can't paste a Numpy array into a `PIL Image`. You need to make the Numpy array into a `PIL Image` first:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

imageWidth=5760
imageHeight=2880
image_sheet = Image.new("RGB", (imageWidth, imageHeight), (255, 255, 255))

# Make little image to paste
image=np.zeros((512,512), dtype=np.uint8)
image_sheet.paste(Image.fromarray(image), ...)
```

Also, watch out for the `dtype` !!! Example:

```
image=np.zeros((512,512))
print(image.dtype)

'float64' !!!! which is UNACCEPTABLE to PIL
```

---

Alternatively, you could make the little image directly in PIL:

```
image_sheet.paste(Image.new("RGB", (512,512), 'red'), ...)
```

Comment: PIL accepts `float64` arrays as images just fine. The mode is then `F` (== float32, discarding some precision), and `paste()` converts the mode to match the target image. With `np.zeros()`, there is no precision to lose anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It only accepts floats if greyscale, AFAIK. If you try it with colour, it won't `im = np.full((480,640,3),17.0)` followed by `Image.fromarray(im)` The modes are here https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes

Comment: That's a different issue ;-) That's the default mode detection picking mode `F` and failing to convert the data. Give `Image.fromarray()` a different, explicit `mode` argument like `RGB`.

Answer (score 1):

`Image.paste()` only accepts another `Image` instance, or a pixel colour (which can be a string, an integer or a tuple, depending on the mode of the image).

You passed in a numpy array, and that's not an image, nor is it a valid pixel colour. *Make* it an image first, e.g. by using [`Image.fromarray()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray):

```
image_sheet.paste(Image.fromarray(image))
```

perhaps passing in `image_sheet.mode` as the second argument to `Image.fromarray()`. I left off the `box` argument for `Image.paste()`, because the default is `(0, 0)`.

The way the `Image.paste()` method is implemented, if you don't pass in an image, it assumes you passed in a pixel colour instead, and in that case you *have* to specify a 4-value box, hence the first error message. When you do give it a 4-value box, only then can it tell you that what you passed in is not a pixel colour!